# invalid column name error while using JPA nativequery in netweaver server with Oracle 10g database

Tags: oracle, jpa, jpql, nativequery, netweaver

I'm getting invalid column name error while using JPA nativequery in netweaver server .The database is Oracle 10g

here is my code

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select et.eqt_desc from  ge_equip_type et",GeEquipType.class);
final List<String> equipList = query.getResultList();
```

Following is the exception thrown :

> SQLException occurred executing a query, mapped to select et.eqt_desc from  ge_equip_type et 
>       [EXCEPTION]javax.ejb.EJBException: nested exception is: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: SQLException occurred executing a query, mapped to select et.eqt_desc from  ge_equip_type et
> ..................
>   ..................
>       Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3651)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.findColumn(OracleResultSetImpl.java:2543)
>       at com.sap.engine.services.dbpool.wrappers.ResultSetWrapper.findColumn(ResultSetWrapper.java:87)
>       at   com.sap.engine.services.orpersistence.query.EntityResultFactory$NamedEntityResult.getColumnNumber(EntityResultFactory.java:239)
>       at com.sap.engine.services.orpersistence.core.PrimaryKey.createFromEntityResult(PrimaryKey.java:246)
>       at com.sap.engine.services.orpersistence.core.StoreManager.processEntityRow(StoreManager.java:1631)
>       at com.sap.engine.services.orpersistence.core.StoreManager.resultSet2ObjectList(StoreManager.java:1602)
>       at com.sap.engine.services.orpersistence.core.StoreManager.executeQueryWithoutProcessingEntityInfos(StoreManager.java:1120)
>       at com.sap.engine.services.orpersistence.core.StoreManager.executeQuery(StoreManager.java:1141)
>       at   com.sap.engine.services.orpersistence.core.PersistenceContextImpl.executeQuery(PersistenceContextImpl.java:937)

GeEquipType class

```
package com.jnj.e2.cpl.orm;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Version;

@Entity
@Table(name = "GE_EQUIP_TYPE")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_EQT", sequenceName = "SEQ_EQT", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GeEquipType implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_EQT")
  @Column(name = "EQT_ID")
  private Long uid;

  @Column(name = "EQT_CODE")
  private String code;

  @Column(name = "EQT_DESC")
  private String description;

  @Column(name = "EQT_CLEAN_VAL_SPAN_DAYS")
  private Long cleaningValiditySpan;

  @Column(name = "EQT_INDC_PRODUCT_YN")
  private String inDirectContactWithProduct;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "EQT_PRT_ID")
  private GePrinterType printerType;

  @Version
  @Column(name = "EQT_OLV")
  private Long version;

  public Long getUid() {
    return uid;
  }

  public void setUid(Long uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
  }

  public String getCode() {
    return code;
  }

  public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }

  public Long getCleaningValiditySpan() {
    return cleaningValiditySpan;
  }

  public void setCleaningValiditySpan(Long cleaningValiditySpan) {
    this.cleaningValiditySpan = cleaningValiditySpan;
  }

  public String getInDirectContactWithProduct() {
    return inDirectContactWithProduct;
  }

  public void setInDirectContactWithProduct(String inDirectContactWithProduct) {
    this.inDirectContactWithProduct = inDirectContactWithProduct;
  }

  public GePrinterType getPrinterType() {
    return printerType;
  }

  public void setPrinterType(GePrinterType printerType) {
    this.printerType = printerType;
  }

  public Long getVersion() {
    return version;
  }

  public void setVersion(Long version) {
    this.version = version;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return 31 + (uid == null ? 0 : uid.hashCode());
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
      return true;
    } else if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }

    final GeEquipType that = (GeEquipType) obj;

    if (uid == null) {
      if (that.uid != null) {
        return false;
      }
    } else if (!uid.equals(that.uid)) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

**Note :Query works when i fetch all columns or primary key column but not String columns.**

Anyone please help.

Comment: When you execute the following, are you able to see any results? `select et.eqt_desc from  ge_equip_type et`

Comment: from backend im getting values..When i execute using nativequery im getting following exception:

Comment: Kindly provide the exception you are getting and mention which JPA you are using.

Comment: @user75ponic I have updated my question with the exception. I'm using JPA 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Can you try as

```
String sql = "select et.eqt_desc from  ge_equip_type et";
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql, GeEquipType.class);
List<GeEquipType> equipList = (List<GeEquipType>) query.getResultList();
```

Besides, make sure you have Oracle JDBC JAR files in your project settings.

Comment: I have tried as you mentioned but still getting the same error

Comment: Provide your `GeEquipType.class` by editing your question.

Comment: I have provided the GeEquipType.class

Comment: @sab Honestly, I am clueless as I do not know why you an error when you select String columns in the SQL. Alternatively, you can try using annotations SQL rather than native query.

Answer (score 0):

There are few solutions for this issue
1, You can try @Transient to all the other columns in that table.
2, You can try Hql which can return object[] and convert it to the class after getting list of objects.
3, is to use criteria api to get the query.

The 1 option also is where I have an issue with, where it is working with native query but not with hql. if you code has both native queries and hql using that table, that is a problem I don't know the solution for.